# Git undo pushed commits into a single commit

Tags: git, github

Alright, so I commited some changes with a git username that was saved on my work laptop. After I changed the git username and useremail and pushed the branch to the remote repo, I have several commits under the initial username, and others under the changed username.

Is it possible to either undo the commits under the initial username, merge them into a commit with the current username and push the branch with one single commit that has the changed username ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have 3 commits you want to retract and squash into one:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit
git push -f
```

First, reset Git HEAD to the point before those commits, preserving all content. Then create a new commit as usual, with current names, and force push to override the commits on GitHub.